# Probability distribution for birthday paradox

Tags: probability-distributions, birthday

In Wikipedia we read

> In an alternative formulation of the birthday problem, one asks the average number of people required to find a pair with the same birthday. If we consider the **probability function Pr[n people have at least one shared birthday]**, this average is determining the mean of the distribution, as opposed to the customary formulation, which asks for the median.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people_to_get_at_least_one_shared_birthday)

However no probability distribution $Pr$ is given. What is $Pr$ ?

Comment: Do you know the probability that $n$ people all have distinct birthdays?

Comment: $365!/(365^n(365−n)!) $; but this is not a probability distribution

Comment: Oh, I thought you were asking, "What is $Pr$?", which in bold in your post is the probability that "n people have at least one shared birthday".

Comment: Pr it is not a probability but a probability distribution and a probability mass distribution must add to 1 over all n

Comment: The bold text in you post has ***Pr[n people have at least one shared birthday]***, which is a probability.  It is the probability that n people have at least one shared birthday. It is not a probability distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked page suggests that, ***instead*** of computing the smallest $n$ such that the probability that at least two of the $n$ people share a birthday is at least 0.5, which is the typical "birthday problem",...

...to consider the experiment in which you ask people for their birthdays until a birthday is repeated, with $n$ being the number of people that you needed to ask. If we say that there are only 365 possible birthdays (ignoring Feb 29), then the outcome of this experiment is a random variable that has a probability mass function on the support $n=2, 3, \ldots, 366$.

The probability mass function is defined by:

$$P(X=2) = 1/365$$
$$\text{For $x \in \mathbb{N}, 2<x\le 366$, }P(X=x) = \left[1 - \sum_{i=2}^{x-1} P(X=i)\right]\left(\frac{x-1}{365}\right)$$

The expected value of the random variable is approximately $24.616585$, which can be found numerically using the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np

probs = np.zeros(366)

for i in range(1,366):

    probs[i] = (1-np.sum(probs[:i]))*i/365

print(f"Total probability = {probs.sum()}")

expected = np.sum((np.arange(366) + 1)*probs)

print(f"Expected value = {expected}")
```

[image]

[image]